# concatenate two images one below the other

Tags: command-line, image-processing, imagemagick

Using the `convert` command, we can concatenate `img1.png` with `img2.png`:

```
convert img1.png img2.png +append  full_img.png
```

However, the command above adds `img2.png` to the **right**  of `img1.png`. 
How to add `img2.png` at **bottom** of `img1.png` using the `convert` command?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just:

```
convert img1.png img2.png -append  full_img.png
```

See the manpage:

```
    -append         append an image sequence top to bottom (use +append for left to right)
```

Comment: Preserve the quality: `convert -quality 100 img1.png img2.png -append  full_img.png`